# Distinct two columns and sum a third column

Tags: sql-server, sum, distinct

I have the next table, is called: `mytable`:

```
---------------------------------
|id |  date  | name|actionCount |
---------------------------------
|a1 |03.03.12| ba  |     12     |
|a3 |06.02.13| ba  |     7      |
|a1 |06.02.13| ca  |     2      |
|a3 |06.02.13| ba  |     9      |
|a1 |06.06.13| ba  |     2      |
|--------------------------------
```

I want to get the distinct id and name, and sum them count.

so I have to get:

```
------------------------
|id | name|actionCount |
------------------------
|a1 | ba  |     14     |
|a3 | ba  |     16     |
|a1 | ca  |     2      |
------------------------
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,name,SUM(actionCount) FROM mytable GROUP BY actionCount
```

but I got:

```
Column 'mytable.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either
an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT id,name,SUM(actionCount) FROM dbo.mytable GROUP BY id,name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this...

```
SELECT id,name,SUM(actionCount) FROM mytable GROUP BY id,name
```